How does one (right-)align geom_text() annotations in ggplot flexibly?
I want to write a simple function with which one can visualize some distribution via a dotplot.
In the plot a text annotation should display what values went into the randomly generated data displayed in the dotplot.
Here is a simplified example, where I can choose a value for the mean and the sd of the normal distribution used to generate the data.
my_fun <- function(chosen_mean, chosen_sd) {
  x <- rnorm(50, mean = chosen_mean, sd = chosen_sd)
  data <- data.frame(x)
  p <- ggplot(data, aes(x = x)) +
    geom_dotplot() +
    theme_classic()
  
  annotations <- data.frame(
    xpos = c(Inf,Inf,-Inf),
    ypos =  c(Inf,-Inf,-Inf),
    annotateText = c("text 1",
                     "text 2", 
                     paste0("M = ", chosen_mean, ", SD = ", chosen_sd)),
    hjustvar = c(1.1, 1.1, -2),
    vjustvar = c(5 , -22, -19)) 
  
  p <- p + 
    geom_text(data=annotations,aes(x=xpos,y=ypos,hjust=hjustvar,
                                   vjust=vjustvar,label=annotateText)) 
  
  p
}

my_fun(0, 1)
my_fun(1000, 200)

Depending on how long the string is that is generated by paste0("M = ", chosen_mean, ", SD = ", chosen_sd) due to different mean and sd values, this text box will move around in the plot. I assume the reason is that I used some fixed hjustvar and vjustvar values (here: -2 and -19) that I picked so that the textbox would go approximately where I want it.
I don't understand how this annotation system works (I just adapted it from this post) so it is all very hacky.
My question now is, is there a) a way to align the text box to the righthand side of the plot regardless of the length of the string and b) a more elegant way of achieving this where I wouldn't even have to use separate text boxes for different texts but could instead just use one right-aligned text box with the string written like e.g. paste0("text 1\ntext 2\nM = ", chosen_mean, " , SD = ", chosen_sd).


a) a way to align the text box to the righthand side of the plot regardless of the length of the string

Yes.  Use Inf as the x coordinate, and hjust = 1.
Take the (x,y) exact coordinate at which the text will be set, given by the x= and y= mappings.  hjust indicates which point of the text will be at that coordinate:

When hjust = 0 then the start of the text is will be at that coordinate, meaning that the text is left-aligned.
If hjust = 0.5 then the middle of the text will be anchored at (x, y), making it center-aligned
hjust = 1 will set the end of the text at (x,y) right-aligning it.

You can go outside the 0-1 range:  e.g., -1 will anchor a point before the start of the text to (x,y), so in practice you are left-aligning and adding a margin.  A bit like setting hjust = 0 and adding a bunch of spaces to the beginning of the string.  The reverse applies to values greater than 1: they will right align and add a margin.
Is easier to understand if you imagine a continuous line that has 0 at the start of the string and 1 at the end of the string.  hjust is the point of that line that you want to anchor to (x,y).
vjust works just the same, but for bottom (0), middle (0.5) and top (1).

b) a more elegant way of achieving this where I wouldn't even have to use separate text boxes for different texts but could instead just use one right-aligned text box with the string

Not sure if this is what you want, but does the suggestion above of x = Inf, hjust = 1 (right-aligned at the end of the y-axis) do the trick?  You can even add a bit of padding by using hjust=1.2.
